# What could I use to rate-limit certain internet content?

Tags: router, internet

Much as I would like to just ban access to FaceBook in my household, it'd be political suicide and just a bit obvious.

What I'd like to do is rate limit access to Facebook at certain times of the day so that it kinda works but is just such a pain in the ass to use that the kids go off and do something more productive like reading a book.

I'd prefer to do this at the router and have looked at dd-wrt but don't see how I could do this.

I'd be happy to consider replacing the router (a LinkSys BEFR41) with a Linux or Windows box (the domestic internet access is presented on an ethernet cable by our WiMax provider).

Any ideas?

Comment: easily done with squid proxies on a linux box, but on a CHEAP router idk...I can do it on commercial cisco equipment easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the PC route, I suggest using [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/). It comes with a very nice packet filter called **pf**. You could use it as an Ethernet bridge (transparent) or replace your current Linksys device and do NAT with it.

The configuration and manipulation of your filter with  **pf** is much easier than with Linux. OpenBSD provides many examples in the [pf faq](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/). You could set a script to execute via cron at certain times to assign a give portion of bandwidth to Facebook's IPs.

If you like to try new things, and want a lot of room to grow your ruleset this is the way to go.

Comment: It's been a few years since I worked with a BSD unix (FreeBSD), I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

With dd-wrt or a linux box you would use the [tc command](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Tc_command).